# WooCommerce: Is it possible to run one language on front-end and have Wordpress admin in another

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need the main website language to be in Spanish for the front-end so that the customers can understand the WooCommerce functions and buttons. i.e. "buy now" buttons should be in Spanish "comprar".  However, I would like to maintain the WP-admin in English so that it's easier to manage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Spanish version of WordPress to have Spanish on the frontend and [English WordPress Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/english-wp-admin/) plugin so you would have English language in the admin panel.